# Ошибка экспериментального декоратора в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, discord-api

Получаю ошибку

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "experimentalDecorators": true,        
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         
}
```

Настройки VsCode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непосредственно код

```
    import { Client } from 'discord.js';
import { DynamicMessage, OnReaction } from 'discord-dynamic-messages';

export class NumericEmojiMessage extends DynamicMessage {
    private counter = 0;

    @OnReaction(':one:')
    public increment() {
      this.counter = 1;
    }

    @OnReaction(':two:')
    public decrement() {
      this.counter = 2;
    }

    public render() {
      return `Number: ${this.counter}`;
    }
  }

const client = new Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.on('message', (message) => {
      if (message.channel !== null){
          new NumericEmojiMessage().sendTo(message.channel);
      }
  });
});
client.login("Njg1MTA2MjQwNjgxOTM0OTcw.Xm-1HA.eRnzxS6hEB5Z7XoHLlTqjgsdqYk");
```

Скрин ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перезапусти vscode - мне помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `tscofig.json` добавьте:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ну или используйте, тот который лежит в репозитории: [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Olian04/discord-dynamic-messages/blob/master/tsconfig.json).

Это необходимо из-за того, что для `Method Decorator` нужен `PropertyDescriptor`, который был добавлен только в ES5 ([Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators)).

Comment: У меня отлично работает с ES5.